# Menuitem to cut part of the text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menuitem

The text that is in the MenuItem Header is getting a hidden part, as shown in the image below. The full text is "Informações de Pagamento", but the rest is hidden. I need this component to be this size, width =240

[image]

My axml file:

```
<Image.ContextMenu>

    <ContextMenu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="240">
        <MenuItem x:Name="infoPagamento" Header="_Informações de Pagamento" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Online" Click="statusOn_Click" Background="White" Margin="5" >
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="../Imagens/icons/menuusuario/icon_financeiro.png" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem x:Name="alteracaoPlano" Header="Alteração de plano" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Alteração de plano" Click="statusAusente_Click" Background="White" Margin="5">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="../Imagens/icons/menuusuario/icon_tarefa.png" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem x:Name="Relatorios" Header="Relatórios" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Ocupado" Click="statusOcupado_Click" Background="White" Margin="5">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="../Imagens/icons/menuusuario/icon_relatorios.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem x:Name="Ajuda" Header="Ajuda" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Offline" Click="statusOff_Click" Background="White" Margin="5">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="#48026E" />

                    <Label Content="?" Padding="0" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Cursor="Hand"/>
                </Grid>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>

    </ContextMenu>
</Image.ContextMenu>
```

My Resource:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">

                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        Background="White"
                        BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                        Margin="3" CornerRadius="10">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </Border>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: There is enough space for the cut-off text. I doubt that you have some style elsewhere causing this issue. Try applying some explicit border for your menuitem to see what's wrong.

Comment: @KingKing i tried  <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="230"/>
    </Style> but do not resolve

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem for Menu with drop down style. The problem is in reserved space for shortcut like CTRL+D (input gesture text). To overcome limitation I had to set menu item width to fixed size, override menuitem header with text block, set its width to auto (fixed width did not work like expected) and set negative margin for textblock (its size can be different for your problem).

Some short example:

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True" Height="auto" Width="220" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

<MenuItem BorderThickness="0" Width="220"  Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Ellipse Width="25" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="imgAvatar" ImageSource="..." TileMode="Tile" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Some long long text" Width="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="0,0,-75,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </MenuItem.Header>

    <MenuItem BorderThickness="0" Width="220"  Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Ellipse Width="25" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="imgAvatar" ImageSource="..." TileMode="Tile" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Some long long text 2" Width="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="0,0,-75,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>

</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width of MenuItem as "Auto"